# Azure B2C API wrapper library - Does it exist?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-v2

I have an Azure B2C instance setup. I would like the ability to perform administrative duties such as search for users and set new passwords (not reset to temp password) from a custom ASP.NET Core project for a subset of users in our company. I know I can do this directly via the API directly or powershell.

But I was wondering if there is a c# library/API wrapper out there that would allow me to do this. I am trying to avoid creating poco type objects for users entities, etc and re-creating this "wheel" if it already exists.

I did some research and there was "ADAL" which seems to longer be an ongoing project from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the interactions you are talking about should be possible using the Microsoft Graph SDK.

NuGet:

- `Microsoft.Graph`
- `Microsoft.Graph.Auth`

**Note**: A few of the B2C-specific administration tasks may require the beta version until it gets released.

Nuget: `Microsoft.Graph.Beta`

For example, I am using the Beta API to automate the uploading of my `Identity Experience Framework` custom policies.

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for. And the uploading of custom policies is something that is right up my alley as well. I will also look into that. Appreciate it